# Issue Selected 1 row but update all row from other row primary key Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have to select 1 table 1 row from Eloquent code

```
$ReceiveDetailSelected = ReceiveDetail::where([['subjectid', $subject],['psubid', $request->psubid],['id', $id]])->first();
return $ReceiveDetailSelected;
```

and Result

```
{"no":1,"id":1,"psubid":"1\/2017","pdetailid":"1","subjectid":"7","labid":"1","result":0,"path_file":"3","status":"pending","created_at":"2017-08-14 13:27:59","updated_at":"2017-08-14 15:19:39","deleted_at":null}
```

but In database update all row from code

```
$ReceiveDetailSelected = ReceiveDetail::where([['subjectid', $subject],['psubid', $request->psubid],['id', $id]])->first();
$ReceiveDetailSelected->status = 'pending';
$ReceiveDetailSelected->path_file = '4';
$ReceiveDetailSelected->save();
return $ReceiveDetailSelected;
```

And Full code in function

```
public function storenewwork($id,$subject,$product,Request $request)
  {
    $ReceiveDetailSelected = ReceiveDetail::where([['subjectid', $subject],['psubid', $request->psubid],['id', $id],['no', '1']]);
    $ReceiveDetailSelected->status = 'pending';
    $ReceiveDetailSelected->path_file = '4';
    $ReceiveDetailSelected->save();
    return $ReceiveDetailSelected;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide a more extended code context ? What code is above the sample you provided, what is done with your return... ?

Comment: @ksjohn edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by Add `protected $primaryKey = 'no';` I think laravel has set pk to `id`.It will update all row in `id= 1`

Comment: So you had more than one row with the same id and the rows that were modified were those with that id ? If so, it would be relevent to edit your question to add these details for the users who end up here for the same issue in the future.